# Avoid repeating myself (DRY) with DataContractSerializer and inheritance

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, anti-patterns, known-types

I am trying to write a file header which is a XML string representing some object hierarchy.

This hierarchy at certain points contains subtypes so, for example the class `Plant` contains a property of type `Stem`, but upon serialization, `Root` value can be an instance of any subclass of `Stem`, like `LongStem`, `DryStem` or `RottenStem`. Also, there is a property `Collection<LeafBase> Leaves` whose items can be any subtype of `LeafBase`, like `GreenLeaf`, `SweetLeaf`, etc.

If I only use the default code, DataContractSerializer will give a runtime error complaining about "unexpected type", since it expects an object of Type `Stem` and receives a type `DryStem` instead, for example.

So, some research quickly led me to the Known Types solution, which would demand me to include an array with **every** subclass of the target type (and God knows how many additional layers).

Well this sounds to me like an outrageous violation of DRY and SRP principles, because if every time I add a subclass, I have to go around my source code looking for lists of known types to update (this is the Shotgun Surgery anti-pattern, and is one of the worst characteristics of the previous version of this system).

I have seen a way to use reflection and get said list of Known Types, but it's sort of hackish I guess (not that I care), so my question is:

> What would be a good way to handle DataContractSerialization for a class whose object tree contains a lot of inheritance, regarding DRY and the known-type-list issue?

Alternatively, if there is another type-safe way to serialize and deserialize an object to a XML string, that is immune to this problem, that could be an option.

Comment: Why do you think using reflection is hackish? If you want to be able, at run-time, to determine all your known types, then that's perfectly fine. Also, I don't see how declaring `KnownTypes` is violating SRP or DRY. You do it once, for the base class.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov if I add another subtype, I have to change two places: the subtype declaration itself, and an _update_ to the known types at the base class. That is, base class has more than one reason to change: some genuine change _and_ a change (creation / deletion) of a subtype.

Comment: Why would you need to change the sub-type declaration? You create the sub-type, and look up all classes sub-classing the base class at runtime.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That is highly error-prone, that is the problem: changing one thing in more than one place: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_surgery. I have already walked down that alley, I know what is there and it's not pretty, and I don't want to go back there again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you mean, you can avoid the duplication of declaring your sub-types each time a new one is created by discovering all the types deriving your base class at runtime.

Something along the lines of:

```
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public abstract class Foo
{
    public static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
        Type currentType = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        return currentType.Assembly.GetTypes()
                                   .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(currentType))
                                   .ToArray();
    }
}
```

This would let you set all known types at run-time, without needing to duplicate your `KnownTypes` attribute on each derived type.

**Edit:**

> Could you suggest a way to get types from every assembly in solution
>   instead of just the one where base class is declared?

Assuming you have a single `AppDomain` and the assemblies, you could search `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, which will iterate all types in all loaded assemblies in the current AppDomain:

```
public static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
{
    Type currentType = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                  .SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
                                  .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(currentType))
                                  .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You understood correctly, that is the "somewhat hackyish" way to do it. I asked the question trying to find out alternatives, a more canonical way to do this, or a possible alternative for doing it at all. I'll wait for more answers, otherwise, I'm going to go down _this_ alley. Thanks!

Comment: One question: I have subtypes declared in more than one assembly (for testing purposes). Could you suggest a way to get types from every assembly in solution instead of just the one where base class is declared? I'm quite new to this assembly reflection thing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are all the assemblies loaded at compile time? Or are you loading any of them dynamically (with `Assembly.Load` perhaps?)

Comment: Currently they are all loaded at compile time. Since this system is supposed to be randomly updated with new classes (actual, hardware sensors instead of tree leaves), dynamic loading could be a solution for that in the future, but we have not decided that yet.